# Password protect a python generated xml file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, password-protection

I have generated an excel file with python code on Ubuntu OS using xlwt library. This library is allowing to protect the sheets with password but doesn't allow to protect the whole file. Is there any way to protect the whole file.

I have used the following solution:
https://www.easyxls.com/manual/tutorials/python/encrypt-excel-file.html

But it is setting up its environment by using some external libraries which are not setting up in my system as a lot of user have also complained the same errors/difficulties in installing and setting up environment on ubuntu.

What could be the possible solution to get mu work done with python.

Comment: Did you expand and follow all the steps from 'Find more about Getting Started with EasyXLS' at https://www.easyxls.com/manual/tutorials/python/encrypt-excel-file.html#EasyXLSwithpy4j ?

Comment: I didn't the chance to follow all steps because the first step is setting the environment. 
import clr
import gc
You can't move forward, these libraries didn't install at all. I hv tried my best

Comment: You followed the steps for installing on Windows, check the steps from my link that are for Ubuntu.